# Acceder a archivos en Python

Tags: python

como se darán cuenta soy bastante nuevo en el tema. Últimamente tuve algunos inconvenientes para acceder a mis archivos desde otro .py que se encuentra en un directorio diferente.

El tema es así, tengo un archivo .py que uso siempre y tengo un directorio llamado "practicas" dónde guardo varias cosas que luego intento abrir con el archivo que está fuera de esta carpeta. Así lo hago, o más bien intento:

```
rom pickle import *

externo=open("practicas.Archivo_ser", "rb")
lista=load(externo)
print(lista)
```

Coloco un punto entre el directorio (practicas) y el archivo (Archivo_ser, el cuál no lleva extensión porque es código serializado en binario).
Esto obviamente me tira un error. Pues es básicamente eso, un error muy simple; quisiera saber como se accede a archivos desde Python cuando están en otro directorio. Pensé que debía usar un punto, pero parece no ser el caso.

Desde ya muchísimas gracias.

(Si hago lo mismo pero sin que separe un directorio entre los archivos, funciona a la perfección. Entonces estoy seguro que no es algo mal escrito o que me haya faltado colocar la extensión del archivo.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para abrir archivos de otra carpeta, lo puedes separar simplemente con un forwardslash (`/`)

```
externo = open("practicas/Archivo_ser", "rb")
```

Otra opción es usar `os.path.join()`

```
import os
externo = open(os.path.join("practicas", "Archivo_ser"), "rb")
```

Ten en cuenta que si abres archivos relativamente, se usará la carpeta del entorno de la terminal con la que estás llamando a tu archivo `.py`

Comment: Es mejor usar siempre `os.path.join`, ya que es multiplataforma. El "/" como separador de archivos no es estándar.

Comment: Claro, pero para la gran mayoría de casos (NT / UNIX) va a funcionar correctamente

Comment: Me gustan los programas que funcionan bien siempre.

Comment: Como consulta, en qué caso no funcionaría? Si funciona en ambientes tanto UNIX como DOS, qué más queda? Es que me parece innecesario añadir tantos caracteres cada vez que necesites manejar directorios para algo que a lo mejor ni se acerca al 0.1% del uso, no? simple es mejor que complejo